# zfs send warning: snapshot does not exist (it exists)

Tags: dataset, send, snapshot, zfs

I have the next 'zfs pool' in the machine A:

```
root@machineA:/ # zfs list -t all
NAME                                            USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank                                           7.44M  28.8G    20K  /tank
tank/test                                        92K  28.8G    19K  /tank/test
tank/test@SNAP_2017-June-30_10:00:00              9K      -    19K  -
tank/test@SNAP_2017-July-01_10:00:00              9K      -    19K  -
tank/test@SNAP_2017-July-02_10:00:00              9K      -    19K  -
tank/test@SNAP_2017-July-03_10:00:00              9K      -    19K  -
tank/test@SNAP_2017-July-04_10:00:00               0      -    19K  -
tank/test@BACKUP_from_2017-June-30                 0      -    19K  -
tank/test/exe                                    37K  28.8G    19K  /tank/test/exe
tank/test/exe@EXE_2017-June-29_13:58:49           9K      -    19K  -
tank/test/exe@EXE_2017-July-03_10:00:00           9K      -    19K  -
tank/test/exe@EXE_2017-July-04_10:00:00            0      -    19K  -
tank/test/exe@BACKUP_from_2017-June-29
```

And I want to send a snapshot to the machine B:

```
root@machineB:/ # zfs list -t all
NAME   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank  6.04M  28.8G    23K  /tank
```

With the netcat I can send the snapshots but the system returns me an error very unusual...

If I do:

```
B: nc -w 5 -l 7766 | zfs recv tank/test/exe
A: zfs send -R tank/test/exe@EXE_2017-July-04_10:00:00 | nc -w 5 192.168.99.2 7766
```

All it's ok, but if I do:

```
B: nc -w 5 -l 7766 | zfs recv tank/test
A: zfs send -R tank/test@SNAP_2017-July-04_10:00:00 | nc -w 5 192.168.99.2 7766
```

The stream of snapshots is sent but in the source side I can show:

```
root@machineA:/ # zfs send -R tank/test@SNAP_2017-July-04_10:00:00 | nc -w 5 192.168.99.2 7766
WARNING: could not send tank/test/exe@SNAP_2017-July-04_10:00:00: does not exist
WARNING: could not send tank/test/exe@SNAP_2017-July-04_10:00:00: does not exist
```

Why ZFS takes the dataset `tank/test/exe`? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the snapshots it's complaining about *don't* exist on the source system -- `tank/test/exe` only has `@EXE_<date>` snapshots, while you're trying to send `tank/test/exe@SNAP_<date>`. This warning is appearing because you're sending with `-R` (recursive) from the top-level `tank/test` filesystem, which sends the specified snapshot on the parent filesystem first, and then searches the children for the same snapshot name to try to send those as well. Usually, this only does what you are expecting when you've taken a snapshot on the parent filesystem with `-R` -- on your system, you only snapshotted the parent without snapshotting the child at the same time.

On the sending system, you probably want to change your command to be:

`zfs send -R tank/test/snap@SNAP_2017-July-04_10:00:00 | nc -w 5 192.168.99.2 7766`

Comment: Thank you, you've reason. I'm going to verify if I can execute a `zfs send function` in my app avoiding this warning before change the tree.